# How do I install OpenNI for OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I've installed OpenNI on my system, but CMake hasn't been locating it for some reason. I've tried changing them to the correct path myself, but then I don't know how to set the path for the primesense module. It also seems that every time I set the paths for OpenNI, it causes CMake to error when I configure again. What is the proper way of installing OpenNI for OpenCV?

Answer (score 0):

The following link must help you out, I followed the instructions there, it worked out good for me.

http://seevisionc.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/compiling-opencv-with-openni-for.html

you must cross check whether openni and primesense are in the exact directories which your cmake refers to, if not modify them, it would work.